Have I chosen wrong spoke size?
My MTB has 26" wheels. The rear wheel rim was bent and the hub was also not in a good condition so I ordered a new rim, new hub and spokes. The dimensions of the new and old hub are exactly the same as they are new and old series of Deore. However the rim depths are different between the new and old rim. The old one is a Mavic XM117 with 1.8mm rim depth and the new one has 2.5mm rim depth. Old spokes were 262 and 260 mm but the spokelengthcalculator.com was actually offering 263 and 261mm spokes for my old setup. So I wanted to order 7mm shorter spokes for this new rim which is 256 and 254mm as per recommendation of spokelengthcalculator but online resellers had only 257mm and 255mm spokes available and I ordered them thinking 1 mm difference wouldn't matter much. However after I laced the wheel, the spokes came out from behind the nipples too much (about 3mm or so) even if they have almost no tension. What have I done so wrong?

well, you should always go for shorter rather than longer spokes as they typically stretch a bit under tension. You have probably made a mistake with the ERD of the new rim.

Yes but it's not my fault. The online reseller's website says the rim depth is 25mm but I measured it now as 30mm! Dammit. Too nervous now.

Perhaps they will exchange the spokes, as they are off the shelf items? You can do this!

Do you mean the short spokes? Maybe but I already used the spokes I ordered and this reseller don't have short spokes.
